Asynchronous ajax call prevents navigation to other pages until it loads the data from server. I have async:true but it freezes the browser
Here is my code
$(document).ready(function() {
    getRecordCount();
});

function getRecordCount(){ 
     $.ajax({
        
        type: 'POST',
        url: FULL_PATH + "/my-url/get-data",
        dataType: "json",
        async : true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //loading_btn.start();                                          
        },
        complete: function () {
            //loading_btn.stop();                   
        },
        success: function (response) {

            if (response.success) {
                //console.log("PP:-"+response.count);
                $('#my-count').text("Rec ("+response.count+")");                    
            } else if (response.error) {                    
                console.log("Error while fetching rec count");
            } else {
                console.log("Error while fetching rec count");
            }                
        },
               
    });
    
}

I tried with window.load(), async:true but nothing is working. I want to navigate to other links from the current web page even if the data load takes time.

FYI async : true is the default anyway. That's definitely not the source of your issue. Are you sure that what you've posted is really a [mre] of the issue? Can this code alone cause the problem you're reporting? It seems very unlikely. Have you done any detailed debugging using your browser's developer tools to try to narrow down what might be happening? See also [ask]

Some (entirely speculative) thoughts: Maybe the server-side code this is calling takes a long time / uses a lot of resources / does something which locks a database or other crucial resource? Maybe this AJAX call is accidentally being called multiple times and these many calls are consuming all the available server connections? Maybe a combination of both? Again use your dev tools to investigate.

And what exactly do you mean by "prevents" anyway...specifically what happens if you try to peform navigation during this request - is there an error? Timeout? Some other problem (either visible on screen, or in the dev tools)? It helps us a lot if we have specifics about what does happen, not just what doesn't happen. And also, unless you're opening other pages in new tabs, why do you want to navigate away while an AJAX call is in progress? Don't you, logically, want to wait for the results of the action you've initiated?

Is your server doing some kind of session-based request serialization perhaps? Where the ajax request ties up the session so the server won't respond to other requests using the same session until that request has completed? Some server session mechanisms work that way.

The problem might not be the async: true setting in your AJAX call, allowing concurrent JavaScript execution. However, if the server delays response, the browser may freeze, especially with large data. Optimize server-side code to prevent prolonged processing.

Thanks for editing, but those are not substantive changes. You haven't provided anything which responds to any of the comments or suggestions. The question is in danger of being closed as unclear / lacking debugging info.
